# How to add three row and keep in third column row with Join in mySql

Tags: mysql, join

Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
); 

INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (1, 'Kumar', 'Anil', 'JP NAGAR','BANGLORE');
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (2, 'Kumar', 'Sunil', 'LAXMI NAGAR','Delhi');
```

Data:

```
Personid   LastName   irstName  Address        City
'1'        'Kumar'   'Anil'     'JP NAGAR'     'BANGLORE'
'2'        'Kumar'   'Sunil'    'LAXMI NAGAR'  'Delhi'
```

Table2:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON_DETAIL (
    userid int ,
    email VARCHAR(80) ,
    PersonID int,
    displayname VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO PERSON_DETAIL VALUES (11, 'a@gmail.com', 1, 'AK');
INSERT INTO PERSON_DETAIL VALUES (12, 's@gmail.com', 2, 'SK');
```

Data:

```
userid  email          PersonId displayname 
'11'    'a@gmail.com'  '1'      'AK'
'12'    's@gmail.com'  '2'      'SK'
```

I want Join Like this so that it Give output like this:

```
PersonId  lastnmae   firstname  combineddata
1         Kumar      Anil       a@gmail.com_JpNAGAR_BANGLORE 
2         Kumar      Sunil      s@gmail.com_LaxmiNagar_Delhi
```

Please help me how to Join so that I give desire output.
I have tried Inner Join But unable to get that Output.

Comment: What is the query you've tried?

Comment: What is the `combineddata`? Your sample output isn't clear enough.

Comment: combindeddata is column we have concat  means it will combination of 3 thing which i show in Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `JOIN` with concatenate the strings:

For `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT PE.PersonID, 
       PE.Lastname, 
       PE.FirstName,
       PD.email + '_' + PE.Address + '_' + PE.City AS combineddata
FROM Persons PE
JOIN PERSON_DETAIL PD ON PD.PersonID = PE.PersonID
```

For `MySQL`, please try with [`CONCAT`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

```
SELECT PE.PersonID, 
       PE.Lastname, 
       PE.FirstName,
       CONCAT(PD.email,  '_' ,  PE.Address , '_' , PE.City) AS combineddata
FROM Persons PE
JOIN PERSON_DETAIL PD ON PD.PersonID = PE.PersonID
```

<kbd>[`Working DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c076c/3)</kbd>

Comment: combinded data coming blank

Comment: Your DBMS is `sql-server` or `mysql`?

Comment: mysql is my  table

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment Please check my updated code for `MySQL`, with working demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c076c/3

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
      p.personid,p.lastname,p.firstname,
      concact(pd.email,'_',pd.address,'_',pd.city)as combined_data
from person as p
inner join person_detail pd on p.personid =pd.personid
```

Comment: 11:25:54 select        p.personid,p.lastname,p.firstname,       concact(pd.email,'_',pd.address,'_',pd.city)as combined_data from Persons as p inner join PERSON_DETAIL pd on p.personid =pd.personid LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION Parabola.concact does not exist 0.00045 sec

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select P1.PersonID,P1.LastName ,P1.FirstName,PD.email + '_' + PE.Address + '_' + PE.City combineddata  
from Persons P1 ,PERSON_DETAIL PD
where P1.PersonID = PD.PersonID
```